# How to configure and upload webhook in Bigcommerce store?

Tags: webhooks, bigcommerce, ngrok, cornerstone

I have followed and done all the steps to setting webhook in local system using the bigcommerce documentation 
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/webhooks/setting-up-webhooks

It's working fine with local environment ngrok (It will work for only 8 hours)

But I need to know how to set the webhook in the server?

Do I need to purchase a separate server or can I set it in my theme directory? If so how to set it up? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to set up a separate server to host the app that your webhook is registered to.

When you're ready to move your app from your local machine to a server, you'll want to register your webhook to a destination URL that's a route you've set up on your server instead of an ngrok URL.

For example, if your app was hosted on Heroku and your webhook route was /webhooks, you would send this request to create the webhook on your store:

```
{
 "scope": "store/product/updated",
 "destination": "https://YOURherokuURL.com/webhooks",
 "is_active": true
}
```